# How to detect if a content is using encrypted content store in alfresco?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-enterprise

I am using Alfresco 7.0.x Enterprise version.

I know for storing a content, there are other content store types and `encrypted content store`.
https://docs.alfresco.com/content-services/7.0/admin/content-stores/#encrypted-content-store

How can I identify if a content is using `encrypted content store`?

I think there might be a alfresco database storing the file store paths and corresponding symmetric keys.
Can I search that database for a certain type of content store? What might be the steps?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can search on properties file  `alfresco-global.properties`
if it contain property : `filecontentstore.subsystem.name=encryptedContentStore`

Or using JMX Console like JConsole search for : `JMX MBeans > Alfresco > Configuration > ContentStore > managed > encrypted > Attributes`

Comment: In this way, we can find the default content store settings for the project. 
But for a certain node, it is still not sure(if you are using multiple content store types).

Answer (score 0):

If the content url is in Alfresco Database table `alf_content_url_encryption`, then it is encrypted. Otherwise, it is not encrypted.

https://hub.alfresco.com/t5/alfresco-content-services-forum/how-to-detect-if-a-content-is-using-encrypted-content-store/m-p/312266

Answer (score 0):

Alfresco will use whichever content store you configure for it.
For any alfresco installation configured content store will be visible under alfresco-global.properties file. Look out for the property

```
filecontentstore.subsystem.name=encryptedContentStore
```

If you have not set up anything related to the encrypted content store you are likely to be using the default unencrypted content store. You can see in the documentation that you need to set up keys and other related properties for encrypting all your contents.
Keys are not stored with the content. It is stored in the Keystore.